# How do you add simple 2D plane text?

Tags: three.js

Could someone please enlighten me as to how I add simple 2D text to a scene in three.js? I don't need fancy text geometry.

The purpose of the text is to dimension a 3D rotatable version of this: http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/9823/capturespm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the text with a 2D context, then convert it to a texture and finally display it in 3D space as a particle/billboard.

Comment: im a rookie, could you direct me to an example or which functions i should be looking for?

Comment: You may want to use dom elements on top of the canvas for that kind of stuff.